# Which method of integration do I need?

Tags: integration

How do you integrate;

$$ \frac{x}{x^2 +1} $$

I would like to know which method you use, by parts, substitution etc and the steps on how to carry out the method.

I am trying to teach myself for A-Level but I'm having trouble getting anything to work, so help starting from scratch would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT :
$$(x^2+1)'=2\cdot x$$
with 
$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\log\left|f(x)\right|+C.$$

Comment: I may be completely wrong here, so bare with me. Are you saying that since (x^2 +1)'=2x and then using the formula you've added below then the integral of 2x/(x^2 +1) will equal (0.5)log|f(x)|+c simply because the numerator is 2x rather than just x? So there answer would be (0.5)log(x^2 +1)+C.

Comment: @user173168: What you got is correct!

Comment: That seems so straight forward with the formula! Thank you!

Comment: @user173168: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=x^2+1$ and $du=2x$ then you can integrate using the substitution method. You will need to add a 2 inside the integrand and then $1/2$ outside the integrand.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:} $Note that $\displaystyle (\log(x^2+1))'=\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\dfrac{x\ dx}{x^2+1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{d(x^2)}{x^2+1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{d(x^2+1)}{x^2+1}$$